# The word document cannot be opened after adding excel charts to it using OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I tried to append excel charts to a word document using OpenXml. But after that when I'm trying to open the document it says "Sorry we can't open the file.docx because we found a problem with its contents"
This is my code

```
 public void excelToImages(string excelSource, string wordSource)
    {using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelSource, true))
        {


            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => "Report".Equals(s.Name)).Id;
            var workSheet = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
            var chartParts = workSheet.DrawingsPart.ChartParts;


            using (WordprocessingDocument wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordSource, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPartWordDoc = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                foreach (var chart in chartParts)
                {
                    mainPartWordDoc.Document.Body.Append((chart as ChartPart).ChartSpace as OpenXmlElement);
                }
                mainPartWordDoc.Document.Save();
            }

        }
}
```

Why can't I open the file ?

Comment: I recommend you create this document in the Word UI, as a user. Then use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to see the code required to add a chart.

Comment: Where can I download the Productivity tool ? Could you give me a link ?

Comment: See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425